# How to run several programs that have a while(1) loop simultaneously using Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run two C executables with Popen. Both of them have a `while(1)` loop, and I want them to run simultaneously, but I found it isn't ok.

Here are two C executables:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char str1[20];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 30){
        fprintf(stderr, "hello1\n");
        i++;
    }
    while(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char str1[20];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 30){
        fprintf(stderr, "hello2\n");
        i++;
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Here is the python code:

```
processes=[subprocess.Popen(program,universal_newlines=True,shell=True) for program in ['./hello1', './hello2']]
for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

It only print "hello1" and hangs.

Comment: Have you verified manually that he processes both run?

Comment: Sorry, it is a stupid program.I just write stupid code.It'snot a good question.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to say at all. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue immediately, so I'm trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: If this really was a typo, consider deleting the question as it is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C code has an unreferenced variable `str1`, FYI. Not the problem though.

However, after building both `hello1.exe` and `hello2.exe` with Visual C++, and running your script, I'm not getting the error you have, so it would appear your issue is specific to something else about your setup.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 30) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hello[1/2]\n");
        i++;
    }
    while (1);
}
```

And then this works as you expect:

```
import subprocess

processes = [subprocess.Popen(program, universal_newlines=True, shell=True) for program in ['hello1.exe', 'hello2.exe']]
for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

It prints `hello1` and `hello2` both 30 times and waits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,And i found it can run normally in my system.